# How to draw a double line from GeoJson source in MapBox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using data-driven styles in Mapbox to customize style of lines I get from GeoJson source. Is there any way to draw a double line somehow except than turning lines to polygons or drawing a second line nearby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may consider using the [`line-gap-width`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-line-line-gap-width)
 property.

> Draws a line casing outside of a line's actual path. Value indicates the width of the inner gap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a GeoJSON line</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYXN3b2oiLCJhIjoiY2l5Nmg4cWU1MDA0ejMzcDJtNHJmZzJkcyJ9.WhcEdTYQH6sSw2pm0RSP9Q';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8,
            "line-gap-width": 10
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```